# KML file error: GroundOverlay color change on Google Earth,different from original image

Tags: image, colors, kml

I have this .kml file, which I posted below.On Google Earth .I want to it draws an image overlay draped onto the terrain through using label  .I turned to see the color change .I've been working on this for days,but I don't known why. thanks!
The KML file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <GroundOverlay>
        <name>DLRSRPall_0.dat</name>
        <Icon>
            <href>DLRSRPall_0.dat.bmp</href>
        </Icon>
        <altitude>21</altitude>
        <gx:LatLonQuad>
            <coordinates>
                106.712381310854,26.5706731633437,0 
                106.72683416117,26.5704986412882,0 
                106.727023032012,26.5830885391534,0 
                106.712568602821,26.5832631566659,0 
            </coordinates>
        </gx:LatLonQuad>
    </GroundOverlay>
</Document>
</kml>
```

The image file :[image]
On Google Eatrh:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried converting the image to a PNG or JPEG? That might be more compatible with Google Earth.

Comment: I try it but it doesn't work.i don't known why the color change from red to green.